# Databricks Spark SQL : Array index value from another column for JSON path expression gives error : PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR

Tags: sql, json, apache-spark, databricks-sql

Databricks runtime : 13.2 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.4.0, Scala 2.12)

I am trying to access individual objects from JSON Array using SQL in Databricks. However the array index of the object to select is part of another column.  The SQL works for static Integer value , but not from a integer value from another column.
For example following works :

```
-- Here it is a:[1]
SELECT a:[1] FROM VALUES('[{
        "name": "Let Us C",
        "author": "Yashavant Kanetkar"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rich Dad Poor Dad",
        "author": "Robert Kiyosaki "
    },
    {
        "name": "Introduction to Algorithms",
        "author": "Cormen"
    }
]', 1) AS T(a,b);
```

| output |
| --- |
| {"name":"Rich Dad Poor Dad","author":"Robert Kiyosaki "} |

I get error when the index is dynamic value

```
-- Here it is a:[b]
SELECT a:[b] FROM VALUES('[{
        "name": "Let Us C",
        "author": "Yashavant Kanetkar"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rich Dad Poor Dad",
        "author": "Robert Kiyosaki "
    },
    {
        "name": "Introduction to Algorithms",
        "author": "Cormen"
    }
]', 1) AS T(a,b);
```

Error for above sql

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'b'.(line 1, pos 10)
...
... SQL 
...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:110)
    at com.databricks.sql.parser.DatabricksSqlParser.$anonfun$parsePlan$1(DatabricksSqlParser.scala:77)
...
...
...
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:649)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:492)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:411)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:259)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Please let me know if the information provided is insufficient . Any solution or workaround will be really appreciated. Thank you!

**End Goal** : to have JSON array values in different row without specifying detailed schema using SQL . I.e. explode JSON array. The schema of object in the array is very complex and dynamic , hence can not pass the schema. I just need the array values in different rows.

Comment: What is your desired output given this sample data?

Comment: in the following SQL as value of b is 1, i am expecting 2nd object in the array : 

 SELECT a:[b] FROM VALUES('[{
        "name": "Let Us C",
        "author": "Yashavant Kanetkar"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rich Dad Poor Dad",
        "author": "Robert Kiyosaki "
    },
    {
        "name": "Introduction to Algorithms",
        "author": "Cormen"
    }
]', 1) AS T(a,b);

Answer (score 1):

Following workaround solution works for me , as truly i was looking for all the values from array with its index.

```sql
with json_array ( 
select '[{
        "name": "Let Us C",
        "author": "Yashavant Kanetkar"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rich Dad Poor Dad",
        "author": "Robert Kiyosaki "
    },
    {
        "name": "Introduction to Algorithms",
        "author": "Cormen"
    }
]' as  a, 1 as b ),
array_idx as( select posexplode(from_json(a,"Array<String>") ) as (idx, idx_json) , b  from json_array )
select * from array_idx
where idx = b
 ;
```

Output :
[image]

the SQL function **from_json** is passed with partial schema of **Array** that did the trick.